# Use BeautifulSoup to extract table data from comments

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The data I want is stored inside the comments of the html page. I'm able to access this comment, but can't use the comment to get the data inside it.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import requests


link = https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2020/receiving_advanced.htm

r = requests.get(link).text

stats_page = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')

# What I would normally do to get the rows
# data = stats_page.findAll('tr')

# To get the comment
comment = stats_page.find_all(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, bs4.Comment))
```

Solutions on stack overflow tell me to do

```
data =  BeautifulSoup(comment,'lxml')
```

But this gives an error "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"
Since comment is of class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'

I want to be able to extract the table data in the comment using findAll('tr') and create a DataFrame with it.

Thank you for your help!

Note:
Another solution is:

```
for comments in stats_page.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, bs4.Comment)):
       comments.extract()
```

But I'm not sure where the data is extracted and isn't in stats_page or comments.

Edit:
From the answer below:

```
comment = stats_page.find_all(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, bs4.Comment))
```

makes `comment` a `list`
converting it to a string and creating a soup using:

```
str1 = ''.join(comment2)
test1 =  BeautifulSoup(str1,'lxml')
```

enables of using `test1` for data analysis!

Comment: From the BeautifulSoup documentation "The Comment object is just a special type of NavigableString". Therefore, you're probably going to want to use RE or some custom string parsing to get what you need

Comment: I, for one, am now confused. You say "The data I want is stored inside the comments of the html page" then, later, you say "But I'm not sure where the data is extracted and isn't in stats_page or comments". So where are the data that you want? Maybe give an example of the output you're expecting

Comment: The data is originally in the comments. However, once I got the comment data using 
`comment = stats_page.find_all(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, bs4.Comment))`, I didn't know how to manipulate it using beautifulsoup. By changing the comment from beautifulsoup result format to string and then creating a new soup, I'm able to access and manipulate the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you a `list` of all comments. `.find_all` returns a `list` of items.

```
comment = stats_page.find_all(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, bs4.Comment))
```

You cannot create a soup object from a list. *From above `comment` is a list.*

```
data =  BeautifulSoup(comment,'lxml')
```

That is why you get that Error.

You have to find out the comment that you are looking for by iterating over the `comment` and convert that to `soup` object. Then you can extract your data.